# Make the boolean return to true or false in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my python code. I want to create a function to check if a video is playing a media file which is true or false to get the return boolean.

I have created the function in player.py:

```
def isPlayingVideo(self):
    isPlayingVideo = xbmc.Player().isPlayingVideo()

    if isPlayingVideo == 'true':
       #set it to true
    else:
       #set to false
```

In test.py, I want to check if the isPlayingVideo() have the return boolean which is true or false:

```
import player

if not self.player.isPlayingVideo():
   #ok let do something
```

Can you please show me an example snippet of how I could use to make the boolean to return to true of false when I am using `if not self.player.isPlaying()`??

Comment: Is this all the code? If player.py doesn't contain class, then `self` is not correct. If it is, then you have to instantiate the object and reference that object, say `player = Player()` and change `self.player.isPlaying()` to `player.isPlayingVideo()`.

Comment: is `isPlayingVideo` a method in a class or is it a standalone function?

Comment: Oh sorry, I have forgot to change from `isPlaying` to `isPlayingVideo` in my question so I have updated it. Please see it.

Comment: Are you really using `isPlayingVideo` as both a method name and as a local variable in the definition of that method?

Comment: @JohnColeman yes that is correct

Comment: What possible reason could you have for doing that? Name clashes should be avoided. If you do this sort of thing a lot, sooner or later it will bite you.

Comment: It's possible the OP comes from old versions of BASIC, where assigning a variable with the name of the function is the accepted way to return a value. In Python, however, this is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo You might be right. VBA still works that way, though I would think that before you progress to writing classes in Python you would have encountered the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume that you have built a class into **player.py**, so that it has some structure like:

```
class Player(object):

# other defs, including __init__, etc.

    # and then this
    def isPlayingVideo(self):
        return xbmc.Player().isPlayingVideo()

    # this assumes that xbmc.Player().isPlayingVideo()
    # returns itself a boolean value.
```

Then in **test.py** you need to instantiate the player as an object, so something like

```
import player

my_player = Player() # this make a new object which can call the Player methods.

if my_player.isPlayingVideo():
   # this code will only fire if the return is True
else:
   # handle the False return case.
```

Comment: than you very much for this, but you dont understand what I was asking in my question. I want to create the boolean which I haven't done so to get the return boolean. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 2):

Just return the result of the test, no need for `if`/`else`:

```
def isPlayingVideo(self):
    isplaying = xbmc.Player().isPlayingVideo()

    return isplaying == 'true'
```

The equality test itself returns `True` or `False`, so just use it.

Note: I renamed the local variable because having three things with the same name in closely related scopes is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running this in some form of loop.  If you want a variable to default to a specific value, initialize it at the outset of the for/while loop to the desired value and then in your function, if conditions warrant, have the function return a different value.  ShadowRanger's code will work also and is quite elegant.